# T-Rex Dual Mining Memory Issue

Tags: mining

I'm running a single 3060 Ti LHR card, trying to dual mine ETH+RVN with t-rex. I set the virtual memory on my C drive to 40000 initial, 60000 max just based on other comments I've seen, but it looks like my GPU is still only showing 7 GB of memory in total (4.52 + 2.47 remaining = 6.99 GB). I can mine each one individually without issue, but dual mining fails. Any ideas?

```
20211104 18:49:47 conn2: Extranonce is set to: 1e
20211104 18:49:47 conn2: Authorizing...
20211104 18:49:47 GPU #0: intensity 21.3
20211104 18:49:47 conn2: Authorized successfully.
20211104 18:49:47 conn2: New target is set to: 4.29 G
20211104 18:49:47 conn2: kawpow epoch: 267, block: 2003395, period: 667798, diff: 4.29 G
20211104 18:49:47 conn1: Using protocol: stratum1.
20211104 18:49:47 conn1: Authorizing...
20211104 18:49:48 conn1: Authorized successfully.
20211104 18:49:48 conn1: ethash epoch: 451, diff: 10.00 G
20211104 18:49:50 GPU #0: generating DAG 4.52 GB for epoch 451 ...
20211104 18:50:04 GPU #0: DAG generated [crc: 9a4ee988, time: 14066 ms], memory left: 2.47 GB
20211104 18:50:05 TREX: Can't find nonce with device [ID=0, GPU #0], Device does not have enough free memory to hold the DAG for epoch 267. Required: 3.09 GB, free: 2.47 GB.
```

Comment: Mining ETH is not longer possible due to the merge

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer, dual mining ETH and RVN requires 10 GB of video RAM but the 3060 Ti only has 8 GB. So. Switching to ERGO.